# Exception ClassNotFound when grails .war file runs on different JDK than it was built with

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

When I execute "grails war" then grails builds me a war file. I deploy it into tomcat's webapps folder, and it runs fine - if I build the war and run tomcat with the same JDK.

If I build the war files running grails on JDK7 and deploy them in tomcat on JDK8, I run into problems - during an API request, I get an error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/HashMap$Entry

It seems that this class from JDK7 is getting compiled into the war (or a reference to it), and it's not found when running on JDK8.

Is there a way to make grails pull in the definition to the class so that a war built with 7 can run on 8 - something like you can do with javac using bootclasspath and extdirs, maybe.

Is there a way to build with 7 and run on 8 (and jdk 7 too)?

Comment: Being more specific would really help here. How does the call "fail" ?

Comment: Hi James, I added some detail on what fails: it's looking for a class from JDK7, which the war was compiled with, and that breaks it when on 8.

Answer (score 0):

Always old version files can be run to latest new version e.g. You can run JDK-7 files in JDK-8 but JDK-8 files will not be run in JDK-7

To avoid this problem compile all your JDK's file in older version for example compile all JDK-8 files using JDK-7 or use one JDK environment

Comment: Notice in my question I specifically mentioned building a war in 7 and running in 8 doesn't work

Comment: is your system 32 bit or 64 bit and what about the system where you are deploying?

Comment: Build and deploy on same system: macbook pro (Mavericks - 64 bit)

Comment: Which JDK environment variables set as JAVA_HOME and which JDK is used by Tomcat?

Comment: Hi Ghayel, thanks for the help. I build the war with jdk 1.7.0_80 and run tomcat on jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: Well @user5655627 we are giving time to fix your problems at our earliest but its not fair that you neither accepted my answer or voted up